# Focal Mean of neighbors using ST_DWithin on points in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm trying to calculate focal means on a grid of points in PostGIS.

I know that a raster calculation would be more efficient, but I only need to run the algorithm once to get the data, so I don't mind letting it run and waiting.

If you think there's a much faster way to do this, including conversion to corresponding format and back, please let me know. I'm primarily interested in understanding how to do this in PostGIS (because I'm tyring to learn PostGIS right now), but I'm open to hearing other ideas if you think this is an atrocious thing to do.

If I understand this correctly, the query below should, for each point, find the neighboring points that fall within 360 projection units and give me a count and average value drawn from the neighboring points.

```
select
    a.grid_id,
    a.pt,
    count(b.pt) as count,
    avg(b.co2perday) as co2perday
from avgs_pts as a 
join avgs_pts as b
    on ST_DWithin(a.pt, b.pt, 360)
group by a.grid_id, a.pt;
```

1. Does this do what I think it does?
2. I've already created a spatial index using `CREATE INDEX pt_index ON avgs_pts USING gist (pt)` and `VACUUM (analyze) avgs_pts`. Is there anything else I can do to make this query more efficient in PostGIS?

Comment: Your points are already in a grid pattern but you don't want to use a raster method? Is it a regular grid? Your proposed mean appears to not be distance-weighted -- is that what "focal" mean is? Does it appear to work, for small distances?

Comment: @martinf 1. I'd *prefer* to use a PostGIS method, but I'm open to raster methods if this would be considered a misapplication of sql. 2. yes, but not rectangular (there are numerous holes and the boundary of cells is irregular) 3. I assumed focal simply meant calculating the mean based on the local neighborhood of each. 4. I've run it and it appears to run in about 40 seconds on 360,000 points, the result appears correct.

Comment: Only if it takes too long or gives wrong answers is it "a misapplication of sql"! (Whatever works, eh.) The question, to *me* is: a) is "focal mean" the right technique for what you want, and b) does your SQL do it right?

Comment: Although i have Dana Tomlin's book (where focal mean and lots of other raster geo-processes are presented) i find it a hard read indeed, so i cannot answer. However,...

Comment: Spatial averages usually calculate some kind of *distance-weighted* mean, perhaps 1 / D-squared, to give decreasing weight to farther away points. Also, if your points are not evenly distributed, you will have bias.